# How to create a Country pick list with country names in the new format?

Tags: web2lead, address

I have finally enabled the new country picklist in my org.

I configured the countries through the Setup-> Configure States

[image]

I wanted to create a new web-to-lead form, using the new country field.

Going to the setup page,

[image]

The resulting HTML does NOT have the country names, but only the country codes.

[image]

Any ideas ?

I am sure it needs to have the Name as Name and Code as value, but both to have the code is wrong IMO.

Comment: how did you configure the countries that you want to use in your organization?

Comment: see edit: Country and Country Code

Comment: I don't have documentation for this, but based on comments overheard at Dreamforce, the feature is still in public beta/working out kinks - like this.  All other picklists have the same display name and value, and they clearly haven't built out the functionality here yet.  Until they do, I think you have to manually update your form.  You can probably copy HTML from the standard Account page > view source.

Comment: Hi Saariko. You wrote, "I am sure it needs to have the Name as Name and Code as value, but both to have the code is wrong IMO." Actually, the only part that matters is the "value" parameter in the option tag. You can change the text displayed to whatever you want, code or picklist label; as long as the value matches a state/country code, the lead should be able to be saved.

Comment: Actually, can you try setting a language (not "default") in the Web 2 Lead setup page?